# Spring MVC InternalResourceViewResolver - Not able to display my page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was attempting to learn `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver`

I have followed this tutorial:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internalresourceviewresolver-example/

But I am not able to get it to work.  I get "Requested resource (/**/) not available"

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">`
<display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>WelcomePage</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is the code for the controller class:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;
public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController{

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("WelcomePage");

        return model;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for servlet config:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

    <!-- Register the bean -->
    <bean class="WelcomeController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Why do I get page not found error?

I have a jsp file in the following location:

/WEB-INF/pages/WelcomePage.jsp

Environment
Tomcat 7
Spring Framework 3.0.2
Net Beans 7

Regards,
Nazir

Comment: You should defiantly have a look at Spring 3 MVC! You are doing Spring 2 MVC, this style is deprecated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, because I have used Spring 3 for the last years, and not Spring 2. But I think the problem is not the `InternalResourceViewResolver`. I think the problem is that the controller is not invoked at all!

I believe in Spring 2 there was something , we needed to make additionally to make spring know how an incoming request is mapped to an Controller based on the url.

To verify that: I would recommend to set an Debugger Breakpoint in the Controller, then see if the Controller is invoked at all.

On the other Hand, you can also download the complete example from the tutorial and check if that works like you expected.

*BTW: I already mentioned (in the comment) that this controllers (extend `AbstractController` or `AbstractFromController`) are Spring 2, and are deprecated in Spring 3.*

Comment: Thanks Ralph. I took your advise and read through the Spring 3 MVC docs and implemented it.  Now my tutorial is workin.